# create a subquery in a SELECT that returns a row of results

Tags: sql, optimization

Can we create a subquery in a SELECT that returns a row of results?

For example, I have have to use a query that looks like:

```
SELECT columnA as aliasA, columnB as aliasB,
(SELECT columnC FROM table2
WHERE clause2) as aliasC,
(SELECT  columnD FROM table2
WHERE clause2) as  aliasD
FROM table1
WHERE clause1
```

I would like to improve it cause it takes too mush time to execute.
Is there any way to create a query like:

```
SELECT columnA as aliasA, columnB as aliasB,
(SELECT columnC, columnD FROM table2
WHERE clause2) as (aliasC, aliasD)
FROM table1
WHERE clause1
```

Thanks

NOTE :
To be more specific, I give you an example :
I need to get the best and worst result of a student on each month of the first quarter. 
If i join the tables, i'll have more than one row for the same student (one for each month) But I need :

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, 
(SELECT MAX(value) FROM results WHERE results.student_id = student.id AND results.date
BETWEEN 'JAN-01' AND 'JAN-31') AS best_result_of_jan,
(SELECT MIN(value) FROM results WHERE results.student_id = student.id AND results.date
BETWEEN 'JAN-01' AND 'JAN-31') AS worst_result_of_jan,
 ..., 
(SELECT MIN(value) FROM results WHERE results.student_id = student.id 
AND results.date BETWEEN 'MAR-01' AND 'MAR-31') AS worst_result_of_mar 
FROM student 
WHERE student.has_maths = 1
```

Comment: Use a join statement if possible, it would be faster than sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname,
       t.best_result_of_jan, t.worst_result_of_mar
FROM student s 
LEFT JOIN (
    (SELECT student_id,
            MAX(CASE WHEN results.date BETWEEN 'JAN-01' AND 'JAN-31'
                     THEN value ELSE NULL END) best_result_of_jan,
            MIN(CASE WHEN results.date BETWEEN 'MAR-01' AND 'MAR-31'
                     THEN value ELSE NULL END) worst_result_of_mar
     FROM results
     GROUP BY student_id
    ) t ON t.student_id = s.id
WHERE s.has_maths = 1
```

The subquery pivots the data into the columns required, for each student. The outer query then adds these columns to the student table columns.

---

First of all, your original query will ONLY work if the subqueries return a scalar result, i.e. single row or none. That makes it safe to convert to a LEFT JOIN form, which can also result in a single row (no cartesian product) or no rows (fizzed join).

```
   SELECT a.columnA as aliasA, a.columnB as aliasB,
          b.columnC as aliasC, b.columnD as aliasD
     FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON clause2
    WHERE clause1;
```

Make sure you alias the columns in clauses 1 and 2.

Note: The plan for such a query will cause table2 to be processed once and columnC/D resolved. Your original query could result in a row by row execution of the subqueries, and twice to boot, hence the lack of performance.

Comment: I can't join them. I'll be more explicite :

Comment: The JOIN condition doesn't **have** to concern `table1` at all. It's just a technique to merge the columns.

Comment: Curious: Where have you heard the term "fizzed join"? I tried to search for it, and the major search engines tell me that it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Guffa `a` was reaching to ignite with `b` but `b` wasn't there so the love *fizzed* over? :)

Comment: Thank you RichardTheKiwi. Your second answer was almost what i was looking for.
It's not the most optimised but it helped me a lot.
The only thing i changed is the use of "case".
The query is faster if you make multiple left join on your different cases.
But thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You want a join, something like:

```
SELECT table1.columnA as aliasA, table1.columnB as aliasB, 
       table2.columnC as aliasC,
       table2.columnD as aliasD
FROM table1 left outer join
     table2
     on clause2
WHERE clause1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query if the data range params are same then you can write a single select statement with min and max fields on value. In your current case apart from other solution you may try a UNION ALL statement and combine two sets of queries. This may be more speedier than the subquery approach. Example:

```
Select A.FirstName,
   A.LastName,
   Sum(A.Best_JAN) as BEST_JAN,
   sum(A.Worst_MAR) as WORST_MAR
From (

    Select student.FirstName,
            student.LastName,
            MAX(result.value) as Best_JAN,
            0 as Worst_MAR
      From Student, Results
     Where Student.Studentid = Results.studentid
       and results.date BETWEEN 'JAN-01' AND 'JAN-31'
     Group By student.FirstName, student.LastName

    Union ALL

    Select student.FirstName,
           student.LastName,
           0 as Best_JAN,
           MIN(result.value) as Worst_MAR
      From Student, Results
     Where Student.Studentid = Results.studentid
       And results.date BETWEEN 'MAR-01' AND 'MAR-31'
     Group By student.FirstName, student.LastName

  ) as A

  Group By A.FirstName, A.LastName
```

Comment: This is a solution but what if I don't select only numbers (the title of the exercise for example ) from the results table. I can't use SUM anymore

Comment: @sllly, as title of exercise is descriptive, you can write it in Select statement and group by clause. The only problem i see with this  logic is that if two students have the same first name and last name then the results will not be right, so adding student id in select and group by clause will resolve this problem